# node.js sharing javascript file between client and server

Tags: node.js

I want a JavaScript file to be included in my client as well as server.

Having some issues. Please help me.

Code:

```
require('app.js');
```

or

```
<script src='app.js'></script>
```

Which one should I use?

Comment: try http://browserify.org/

Answer (score 1):

You can use Browserify to bundle your node module then import that js file with:

```
<script src='app.js'></script>
```

The `require()` function will now be on the global namespace and you can call the following to make the module available to use:

```
var app = require('app.js');
```

Note: in Browserify you'll need to export the module you want to import using require.